# What is the correct way to check if a bitflag is set in a bitmask?

Tags: performance, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

The first method performs a bitwise and with the bit mask and the bit flag and checks 
whether the result of the bitwise and is true (not equal to zero).
The second merthod performs a bitwise and with the bit mask and the bit flag and checks whether the result of the bitwise and equals the bit flag.

Which method should I use to to determine if a bit flag is set? Which method performs better?

Comment: "Which method performs better?" - Does it matter?

Comment: No. I am just interested in an answer to my question.

Comment: The testing you did while doing your research prior to asking your question should answer the performance part of your question, at least for the specific platforms you tested. Of course, a question for the performance on all platforms would be far too broad for the StackOverflow format. Without the performance part, what other criteria do you want to use to evaluate which is the better option, if either?

Comment: I don't know any criteria.